# Campo de busca dentro de select box como fazer?

Tags: php, html-select

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de colocar um campo de busca dentro de um select box, pois por exemplo...tenho um selectbox com +3000 mil itens cadastrados, aí surge a minha necessidade de ter um campo de busca para agilizar o lado do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na foto acima está o meu select box normal com todos os itens...

Alguém já teve essa necessidade? é possível fazer isso com HTML e PHP ?

Comment: Dentro de um select não é possivel, mas podes fazer um select próprio com outros elementos como `div` e aí teres mais liberdade para inserir inputs.

Comment: isso normalmente é feito por javascript onde apenas tens de compor um array de valoires por defeito. quando a lista é pequena (até cerca de 200) uso o [typeahed](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead), se não dá uma olhada a este plugin: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o select2.js, é um componente de busca igual ao select que você esta usando, porem ele faz chamadas ao servidor com ajax filtrando pelo valor digitado no mesmo. Acredito que seja o que você precisa.

Para usar é muito fácil
Adicione esses 2 arquivs no head de seu site

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

e para usá-lo basta fazer o seguinte:

Monte o html:

```
    <select class="js-data-example-ajax">
      <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
    </select>
```

e crie o javascript responsável por configurar o componente:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

Caso precise de mais informações basta acessar o site oficial:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Não entendo porque negativar esta resposta sendo que é semelhante as outras respostas já postadas aqui nesta pergunta. Explica bem o funcionamento do uso do `select2`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! É isso mesmo o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Tem um plugin js que chama [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). Dê uma olhada na documentação do mesmo.

Só importar a biblioteca do cara:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Depois é só fazer isso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".meuselect").select2();
});

<select class="meuselect">
  <option value="1">Opcao 99</option>
  ...
  <option value="99">Opcao 99</option>
</select>
```

Qualquer coisa que precisar, pode chamar :)

Comment: Select2 é um plugin muito bacana mesmo e parece o ideal para atender a pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado! É isso mesmo o que eu precisava.

Comment: @CharlesFay por nada cara. Se esta foi a resposta que queria, por favor, marque a mesma como a correta. Obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

```js
function fnBuscaSelect(busca, select) {
  var valorABuscar = busca.value;
  var selectedTrends = document.getElementById(select);
  valorIndex = selectedTrends.selectedIndex;
  var soprineiro = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedTrends.length; i++) {
    valorTextSelect = selectedTrends.options[i].text;
    //se achou o dado dentro do que digitou então mostra.
    if (valorTextSelect.indexOf(valorABuscar) > -1) {
      if (soprineiro) {
        soprineiro = false;
        valorIndex = i;
        //valorText=selectedTrends.options[i].text;
      }
      selectedTrends.options[i].style.display = "";

    } else {
      selectedTrends.options[i].style.display = "none";
      selectedTrends.options[i].selected = '';
    }
  }
  if ((soprineiro) && (valorABuscar != "")) {

  }
  //selectedTrends.selectedIndex=i; 
  //    selectedTrends.options[selectedTrends.selectedIndex].value=selectedTrends.options[i].value;
  //    selectedTrends.options[selectedTrends.selectedIndex].text=selectedTrends.options[i].text;
  //    selectedTrends.open();

  selectedTrends.options[valorIndex].selected = 'selected';
  //    selectedTrends.focus();

}
```

```html
<input type=text value="" placeholder="Busque o cliente aqui." onChange='fnBuscaSelect(this,"DE_CLIENTE");'><br>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).